# Modificar el estado de un componente dos o más en una misma función ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo un state que necesitaría modificar dos veces ya que hago calculos en base a otras propiedades

```
const [servicio, setServicio] = useState({
    tipoServicio:'Completo', 
    totalServicio1:0,
    totalServicio2:0,
    totalServicio3:0,
    totalServicio4:0,
    descuento:0,
    abonado:0,
    total:0
});
```

Cada `totalServicioN` esta vinculada a un input, con el onChange modifico el valor de la siguiente manera:

```
  function handleChange(e){
        setServicio({
            ...servicio,
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        });
    // aquí necesitaría ejecutar alguna funcion para realizar calculos y asignar
    // a la propiedad total u otras los resultados de dichos calculos,
    // sería otro setServicio dentro de esta función.

  };
```

El requerimiento sería mostrar algunos cálculos entre las propiedades cuando se modifican desde un `form`.

Modificar el valor del input y posteriormente realizar una serie de cálculos y actualizar el total (o los totales).

Con useEffect se crearía un loop infinito ya que modificaría muchas veces el estado.

Comment: ¿Cual es la finalidad de usar useEffect? Así como presentas el problema, los `inputs` estan siendo controlados por react y además, estas usando propiedad computada por cada `onChange`, los cálculos suceden por cada `onChange`, ¿Ya lo probaste así y presenta problemas? ¿Necesitas calcular en cada `onChange` (cada keystroke)?Saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder @g.4
Lo del useEffect es solo un comentario.
Sí, cada input representa un onChange, por cada vez que se realice un onChange se tienen que realizar los calculos y asignar los valores, seria una funcion con que realice los calculos y posteriormente vuelva a llamar a setServicio, pero esto es posible??? Hice un par de pruebas y solo ejecutaba el primer setServicio.

Comment: Parece que hay un hook llamado [`useMemo`](https://codesandbox.io/s/usememo01-grerg), que funciona de tal forma que [memoriza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) ciertos cálculos en la memoria para no sobrecargarla, es muy parecido a `useEffect`, espero poder revisarlo mañana, pero por mientras  tal vez puedas implementarlo por tu cuenta, saludos

Comment: Funciona parecido a useEffect, entraría en un loop que siempre actualizaría su dependencia

Answer (score 0):

Aún no entiendo mucho en que momentos quieres hacer los cálculos o si quieres que constantemente ese realizando esos cálculos pero para ciertos casos puedes colocar en el  objeto del useState un valor booleano y  que cambie cuando quieres que realice el cálculo luego colocas un condicional en tu código y que comprobara el valor del booleano hiciera el cálculo y cambiar su valor una vez echo no se si es eso lo he quieres hacer necesitaría algo más de código o algo más exacto para entenderte mejor

Comment: El requerimiento sería mostrar algunos cálculos entre las propiedades cuando se modifican desde un form.

Cada vez q se modifique algún servicio realizar los calculos.

Comment: Estás intentando modificar el mismo setServicio dos veces  en la misma función?

Comment: Sí, primero para actualizar el valor del input y la segunda vez para actualizar el total y otras propiedades...

Comment: Has dos useState para el total aparte o haz la primera modificación  en esa función y que al terminar llame otra función que modifique  el total prueba hacer algo en el que no tengas que modificarlos dos veces en la misma función y me cuentas.

Comment: El useState no refleja los valores inmediatamente es async si no me equivoco